# SSRS 2017 add datasource "Something went wrong"

Tags: ssrs-2017

when trying to add, view or change data source(s) in SSRS 2017 I get popup saying "Something went wrong, please try later".

Setup os SSRS is as follows:

three SSRS instances behind KEMP load balancer. Communication from clients to KEMP is done over SSL (port 443) and from kemp to SSRS instances over HTTP (port 80). rsreportserver.config file has this tags on all three SSRS servers, where SSRS.domain.com points to the KEMP virtual IP (for client access).

SSRS.domain.com
https://SSRS.domain.com/reportserver

When I try to add, view or change data source(s) I get this error in RSPortal.log

ERROR: OData exception occurred: System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.2.17.11:443
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

10.2.17.11 is the IP of the one of SSRS instances buth what baffles me is why is connection trying to be made using port 443 (TLS) when KEMP is configured to communicate with SSRS instances over port 80.

SSRS instances don't have port 443 configured, only port 80.

Everything else works fine, only datasources are the problem.

SSRS version in question is 14.0.600.1109, native mode.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-a-report-server-on-a-network-load-balancing-cluster?view=sql-server-ver15) to configure a scale-out report server behind a load balancer?

Comment: Hi HandyD, yes, everything is configured as by that article, like I said everything works OK, except adding, viewing or changing data source(s). I have machine key in place, SPNs, hostname (SSRS.domain.com) and URLRoot (SSRS.domain.com/ReportServer).. ReportServerURL is not, as per article

Answer (score 2):

After further investigation I solved the problem by configuring SSRS instances to use both HTTP and HTTPS - NLB is communicating over HTTP but if needed (in case of data sources) SSRS instances accept communication over HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and spent a good amount of time figure out what is wrong and finally, it worked by following the below steps:

1. Uninstall SSRS.
2. Install tSSRS again.
3. Configure the service account, Web Service URL Use the Recommended setting and apply
4. Configure a new Database with an SSO account, Web portal URL Use the Recommended setting and apply

Try uploading the .rdl files and Create Datasource.

Comment: hi @Parth - please consider registering your account which will allow you to login from multiple locations, and receive notifications about responses to your answer(s).  Also, please take the [tour].  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had this "Something went wrong" error when both uploading rdl files and changing data sources. Fixed it by going to uninstall SSRS from the server, and choosing "Repair". Rebooted, and issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved by Removing Multiple URL's from Report Server Configuration Manager from both Web Service URL and Web Portal URL